# Two bag-of-words classifiers, Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, object-recognition

I'm trying to implement "Two bag-of-words classifiers", so I found resources at this website. http://people.csail.mit.edu/fergus/iccv2005/bagwords.html This website provides complete files including Matlab code. But I've encountered some errors while implementing the code.

I run this code on Matlab 2011b , under Windows 7.
At first, some errors occur because of path experession, but this can be soleved. At file "gg_lola_km_binary.m", replace "/" with "\" due to path expression in Windows, and it also needs to allocate appropiate path. After doing this, this error has been solved, but the next error occur:

> `Error using imformats>find_in_registry (line 512)`
>
> `Format specifier must be a 1-D character array.`

I consider whether this error results from Matlab version difference, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes support for bag-of-words in the R2014b release: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html

Answer (score 0):

The error should be something to do with the format of your Input.Not your Matlab version. Most of the written distributed functions are constructed using basic operations and should work on most versions of Matlab (even the older versions); if not it will probably prompt an unknown function being called which it does not recognize.

Your errors seems to say that:
The function imformats>find_in_registry is looking for a 1 dimensional character array, which it did not find. (most possibly in your input file format or file path). I suggest you check again, without further information, we cannot help you.

Comment: OK, I'll try. Thank you for giving me some directions!